# Undefined button click value

Tags: angular

I am getting an undefined value when trying to console.log out a value on button click

TS:

```
  fullView(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <button mat-button (click)="fullView(this.value)" value="full">Expand view</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="fullView(this.value)" value="standard">Expand view</button>
```

Can anyone see why? I am just trying to pass the value to the TS file from the click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below stackblitz

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bj78kc)

```
<button mat-button (click)="fullView($event)" value="full">Expand view</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="fullView($event)" value="standard">Expand view</button>


fullView(e) {
     console.log(e);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
```

Comment: `full
 standard
 undefined
 undefined
 undefined
 undefined
 undefined
 undefined
 undefined
 undefined
 undefined
 undefined
 full`

 This is my console log, it seems that it does not always take the value in/ IS this the best way to do it in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<button mat-button (click)="fullView($event)" value="full">Expand view</button>
```

then you can access:

```
  var target = $event.target || $event.srcElement || $event.currentTarget;
  var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
  var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass the value

```
<button mat-button (click)="fullView(value)" value="full">Expand view</button>
```

Comment: still gives me undefined

Comment: do you have a property for `value`

Comment: no property, it's just a hard coded value in the button

Comment: check @JavascriptLover answer